# Can I make a scrollable table with row count behind high?

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table with a colspan of up to 50, I want to show this in a 600x200 frame.  Is this possible? where you can scroll within the frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes This is possible. you can do this.

Put your table in div and Set the property `overflow:auto` of that div

Comment: Hmm, this isn't working I have:  <div style="overflow:auto;max-width:800px;"> for my div.  Is that right?

Comment: Nevermind, got it to work, you rock thanks!!!